# Pasar texto a otra función

Tags: javascript

Me interesa saber cómo pasar un texto a otra función. Lo que busco hacer es ejecutar una función si la condición se cumple... Por lo que me interesa ejecutarla, pasar un texto y a la vez saber cómo obtener ese texto en la función.

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#texto");
var b = document.querySelector("#text_button");

b.onclick = function() {

var r = t.value;

if (r.trim() = "") {

alert("Ingresa un texto");

} else {

funcion2("Un texto aquí");

}

}


function funcion2() {

/* Recibir texto */

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">
<button id="text_button">Comprobar</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade un parámetro a la función `funcion2()`:

```
function funcion2(texto) {

    alert(texto);

}
```

Fíjate también que tienes un error en el `if`, para comparar se utilizan 2 símbolos de igual `==` o 3 si también quieres comprar el tipo de datos:

```
"1" == 1 // true
"1" === 1 // false
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#texto");
var b = document.querySelector("#text_button");

b.onclick = function () {
    var r = t.value;
    if (r.trim() === "") {
        alert("Ingresa un texto");
    } else {
        funcion2(r);
    }
}

function funcion2(texto) {
    alert("Texto recibido: " + texto);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">
<button id="text_button">Comprobar</button>
```